# Replace Woocommerce coupon amount line by a custom string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

currently in checkout page and cart page after people apply coupon code then cart showing coupon name and how much money reduced from original product price .

For example product price is 100 and discount is 20% for coupon then it showing coupon name , -20 .

But i don't want to show -20 there , instead i need to display custom string there like  20% off . Not the amount , but some custom string ..

How i can do this ? . When i search i can find that theme/woocommerce/cart/cart.php  there it is using a function    `<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' ); ?>` . So there is no option for to edit the reduced amount .

So please help , please note  that this string need to displayed in checkout , cart , order email etc .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html` filter hook like in this example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html', 'custom_cart_totals_coupon_html', 30, 3 );
function custom_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon_html, $coupon, $discount_amount_html ) {
    // For percent coupon types only
    if( 'percent' == $coupon->get_discount_type() ){
        $percent              = $coupon->get_amount(); // Get the coupon percentage number
        $discount_amount_html = '<span>' . $percent . ' % </span>'; // Formatting  percentage
        // Replacing coupon discount, by custom percentage
        $coupon_html          = $discount_amount_html . ' <a href="' . esc_url( add_query_arg( 'remove_coupon', urlencode( $coupon->get_code() ), defined( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT' ) ? wc_get_checkout_url() : wc_get_cart_url() ) ) . '" class="woocommerce-remove-coupon" data-coupon="' . esc_attr( $coupon->get_code() ) . '">' . __( '[Remove]', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
    }

    return $coupon_html;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

It will replace the discounted amount by the coupon percentage on cart and checkout pages…

Comment: @abilasher I have answered it… check :)